# How to add reputation to stack overflow answers?

Tags: discussion

I am new to stack overflow and i don't know how to add/mark reputation or points to those who answered a question in stack overflow. Can anyone give me steps? Thanks.

Comment: Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Comment: Are answer and comment different? (According to "What should I do when someone answers my question?") link is to mark a check beside an answer and i could not find any check beside your answer to mark/vote.(the one that is above this comment).

Comment: I posted a comment, yes, not an answer. You cannot mark comments as accepted, those are just meant to ask for clarifications, and similar. You cannot mark a comment as accepted.

Comment: You really want to re-read the [Stack Overflow About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.

Comment: And I for one commend you on coming here to ask to make sure that you get it right and give people the credit that they deserve for helping. Good attitude! +1

Comment: @Fluffeh: well, the OP didn't come here; this post was migrated from Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's just a technicality and clearly an oversight :) So he asked in the wrong place, in my eyes this is still a good question for a new user to ask. At the absolute least it shows appreciation and respect for the folks answering. Also, I may or may not have had a few glasses of wine this evening, so this whole "Migrated from SO" business is just a footnote. Ahem... I will be moving right along now sir...

Comment: I really did not notice i had migrated from Stackoverflow.com. It's just now that I've noticed when I look up on the url above. Hehe. Then it led me to the question, "what's the difference of the two aside from having the other domain, -meta-?" Are they competing? How about stack exchange? I'm just confused.

Comment: It's clearer to me now. I have the answer to m own question at this site. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange. Thanks guys for being patient to me. :)